# Set minimum scale on QGis Print composer (atlas)

Tags: qgis, print-composer, scale, atlas

I have a template ready to be printed on Print composer tool of Qgis. I need to fix a minimum scale while figures are represented one by one (1:10000)
I would like to combine the scale tool controled by Atlas which sets a 10% margin of the figure, with a precondition of setting minimum scale at 1:10000.
Base cartography is 1:10000 and sometimes figure is really small so Atlas represent the figure with a margin of 10% so scale could be 1:2000 and resolution of base cartography is bad.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by using the option `predefined scale`. The predefined scale relates to a scale set that can be defined under `Properties -> Project -> View Settings`.

The atlas will choose the best fit among the defined scales. If you set the lowest possible scale to 1:10000 no lower scale will be chosen. It works well if you add even steps (for example every 2.500 or 5000 units) above the minimum scale you want to use.